# conv.data lost in followup intent in DialogFlow

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm using node.js 8 runtime in my Google Cloud function, attached to my DialogFlow app (V2 API).
I can use conv.data to store temporary data within the current conversation. Unfortunately, conv.data does not seem to retain data after a followup intent.
For example, in my intent the following code:

```
conv.data.result = "Hello!";
console.log("[DEBUG] conv.data.result = "+conv.data.result);
conv.followup("customEvent1");
```

produces the following log:

```
[DEBUG] conv.data.result = Hello!
```

This is my followup intent:

```
app.intent('CUSTOM_EVENT_INTENT', (conv) => {
  console.log("[DEBUG] - CUSTOM_EVENT_INTENT");
  console.log("[DEBUG] - conv.data.result = "+conv.data.result);
  if(!conv.data.result) {
     console.log("[DEBUG] - I give up");
     conv.close("Nessuna risposta");
  }
  else conv.ask(conv.data.result);
});
```

which produces the following log:

```
[DEBUG] - conv.data.result = undefined
[DEBUG] - I give up
```

Looks like I'm missing something very important in followup intents...
Thanks,
Roberto

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using context instead of data. Context has few more advantages over data objects. It can be accessible in multiple dialog and intents.

```
function getParamFromContext(key){
    // get the value set earlier in the context
    let globalContext = agent.context.get('global_main_context');
    return globalContext.parameters[key];
}
function updateGlobalContext(agent, key, value) {
    // create a global method to maintain all required data within conversation
    let globalContext = agent.context.get('global_main_context');
    let param = globalContext ? globalContext.parameters : {};
    param[key] = value;
    agent.context.set({
        name: 'global_main_context',
        lifespan: 5,
        parameters: param
    });
}
```

Call the method within a conversation with agent object.
**in app.js**

```
intentMap.set("Size Intent", setSize);
function setSize(){
  let size = agent.parameters.size;
  updateShippingObjectContext(agent, 'size', size);
}
```

Comment: FYI, conv.data also persists through multiple dialogs and intents, it is available in every step of a conversation.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! How to get agent object in DialogFlow V2 ? I only have the conv object.

Comment: @RobertoVergallo you can pass agent object as well in callback instead of conv, it should work

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about [Followup Events](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/events-custom#webhook) rather than  Followup Intents. Followup Intents are set as Intents that may be triggered after an Intent has by the user doing some action - this is done by setting a Context. Followup Events are set during fulfillment and are intended to trigger an Intent that has this Event set.

**In most cases, you don't need to use Followup Events.**

Instead - just call a function that does the processing and replies how you want it to do. There is nothing saying that your Handler function has to do everything itself - it can call a function just like any other function, and can call it with parameters.

So it is perfectly reasonable to have Intent Handlers like

```
app.intent('intent.one', (conv) => {
  reply( conv, "Hello!" );
});

app.intent('intent.two', (conv) => {
  reply( conv, "How are you?" );
});

app.intent('intent.quit', (conv) => {
  reply( conv );
});

function reply( conv, msg ){
  if( !msg ){
    conv.close( "I give up!" );
  } else {
    cov.ask( msg );
  }
}
```

**That still doesn't explain why it didn't work.**

What you are "missing" with how you use Followup Events is that using `conv.followup()` does not send *anything* that you may have sent back to Dialogflow when it redirects to the Event. As [the documentation](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/2.12.0/classes/_service_dialogflow_conv_.dialogflowconversation.html#followup) says:

> Triggers an intent of your choosing by sending a followup event from the webhook. [...] Dialogflow will not pass anything back to Google Assistant, therefore Google Assistant specific information, most notably conv.user.storage, is ignored.

What you *can* do, however, is send parameters to the new Intent that is detected from the Event. Something like this might work:

```
const params = {
  result: "Hello!"
};
conv.followup("customEvent1", params);
```

and then in the handler for the event's Intent:

```
app.intent('CUSTOM_EVENT_INTENT', (conv) => {
  console.log("[DEBUG] - CUSTOM_EVENT_INTENT");
  console.log("[DEBUG] - conv.parameters.result = "+conv.parameters.result);
  if(!conv.parameters.result) {
     console.log("[DEBUG] - I give up");
     conv.close("Nessuna risposta");
  }
  else conv.ask(conv.parameters.result);
});
```